# which feature selection technique would be suitable for this dataset

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, feature-selection, feature-engineering

i want to do binary classification with this dataset
dataset is numerical and i am manually adding "class" feature to the dataset with binary values (0,1) or (benign, malicious) depends on either feature selection technique require numerical or categorical output variable. but still i am not getting the results. i want your suggestions, whcih feature selection techniques are suitable for this dataset?
the classifiers i am using are LR,SVM and RF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by plotting the ["pairplots"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) using Seaborn library. This method will plot the distribution of each feature on the dataset and the scatterplot of the features between each other. You will be able to see your plotted samples separated by class.